# mongoose schemaOption versionKey

Tags: typescript, mongoose, typescript-typings

In the mongoose docs they show us to disable the versionKey like this:

```
new Schema({..}, { versionKey: false });
```

But in the @types/mongoose it is a string.

```
versionKey?: string;
```

I am getting this error:

> [ts] Argument of type '{ versionKey: boolean; }' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type 'SchemaOptions'.
>          Types of property 'versionKey' are incompatible.
>            Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'. (property) versionKey: boolean

How do i get to disable versionKey without being annoyed by this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a problem with @types/mongoose.

[I submitted a correction.](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/13163#issuecomment-265632279)